# Python how to split string by number of times

Tags: python, string

Given a string S and an nonnegative integer N, I want to split S into N substrings.

Example:

```
S = 'abc'
N = 2

sub1 = ('a','bc')
sub2 = ('ab','c')
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you show your attempt and explain your difficulties?

Comment: You may want to check out [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: Divide The length of the string by n and use the result to construct slices.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use .split() to split your string into a list of its characters and then use the .join() command to keep on merging characters into lists until you have as many sublists as you want